# Round Python float to 4 significant digits on output, in different numeric ranges

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding, precision

I am looking for a way to round numbers in python (on output) to 4 significant digits.

That is, I want a function, `r4()`, that has this behavior:

```
r4(1.23456) -> '1.235'
r4(12.3456) -> '12.35'
r4(123.456) -> '123.5'
r4(1234.56) -> '1235.'
```

In all of these cases, I round to "4" rather than "5" because I want IEEE rounding mode "Round half Even" (round to nearest with ties going to nearest event integer), so the function should also produce:

```
r4(1.23556) -> '1.236'
```

I've looked at `round()` and at using `.f` formatting, and nothing does this quite right.  I'm thinking about taking it into scientific notation, computing number of significant figures, and then taking it back, but that seems silly.

Comment: I wonder why somebody gave me a -1.

Comment: The rounding you're asking for doesn't match the IEEE round-ties-to-even mode: `1.23456` is strictly closer to `1.235` than to `1.234`, so it should round up, not down under that mode.

Comment: Apart from the rounding direction, `def r4(x): return format(x, '.4g')` seems to be close to what you need.

Comment: Okay...  I'll check it out. Thanks. I guess my example is wrong.

Comment: Can you put your question as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Found the right way to do it:

```
def r4(input_value):
    from decimal import Decimal,ROUND_HALF_EVEN,Context
    ctx = Context(prec=4, rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN)
    return str(ctx.create_decimal(input_value))
```